# dyld[****]: missing symbol called on rails commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm cloning a ruby on rails repository on a 2022 M2 Macbook (ventura 13.4) and when running any rails commands (eg. `rails s`) i am getting this error, `dyld[*five numbers*]: missing symbol called`
I can't seem to find any info on this, but it could potentially be to do with node working on a newer mac?
I have ran bundle install.

See screenshot from error when typing `rails s` -
[image]

Ruby version - 3.1.3

rails version - 6.1.7.2

Comment: Have added the requested

Comment: don't add screen shots -- add the text and more lines of the trace

Comment: I have the same problem there is not more backtrace. For me it is: 
dyld[47804]: missing symbol called after I call any rails command.

Comment: I gave up in the end and used docker instead. Let me know if you find a solution please!