# Mac M1 dyld missing symbol called on Ruby ARM64 installation via RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, apple-m1

I've been cruising along with Ruby on my trusty M1 Mac for a while now, no sweat, especially in good old `x86_64` mode (installed via RVM on a Rosetta terminal). Life was good.

```bash
rvm ls
   ruby-2.7.7 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-3.0.5 [ arm64 ]
   ruby-3.0.6 [ x86_64 ]
```

I decided to embrace the native future and install Ruby 3.0.5 in its native `arm64` mode. Easy peasy, right? Wrong...

Sure, it installs without a hitch, and it even looks like it's behaving. I happily installed my Rails gems through `bundle install`, thinking I was in the clear. But as soon as I try toboot up my Rails app I get slapped with this delightful message:

```bash
dyld[*****]: missing symbol called
```

I even reinstalled `libffi` sith arm64 homebrew as it could be related per some instructions I found in the web but got no success on `rvm reinstall`s since it eventually ended up failing with the same error...

I found [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447424/rails-on-m2-dyld-missing-symbol-called) but it doesn't apply to me because it was related to `mysql` - my project uses `postgres`.
There's another sad, lonely StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76414309/dyld-missing-symbol-called-on-rails-commands) out there with zero answers, and it's like looking in a mirror. A sad, unsolved mirror...

I reinstalled libyaml and libffi and before reinstalling Ruby, no luck. Set the `LDPFlags` pointing to the ffi binaries, also no luck. I did everything I could find online and nothing solved it...

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded from Ruby 2.7.5 to Ruby 3.3.0 and got the same error.
The problem was in this line

```
gem 'therubyracer', platform: :ruby
```

So I just removed it.

Comment: Solved the issue for me. Removed it from my bundle and installed nodejs. Now Rails boots on my M2

Answer (score 0):

It's either some gem with a native extension (most likely) or some other lib/binary that you've installed through Rosetta.

Assuming there's no other info in the error, we'll need to try solving this with a shotgun instead of a scalpel. So I'd start by removing/reinstalling rvm entirely (in fact, I'd take this opportunity to *upgrade* to `asdf`) so you can know none of the gems with native extensions were built in Intel/Rosetta mode.

If that doesn't work, then repeat with homebrew.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and gave `asdf` a try... Unfortunately, same results: `dyld[6026]: missing symbol called` when running `arm64` Ruby 

Is there a way to make the log more verbose or something? Because that dydl message without further context doesn't really help me to debug further...

Comment: So then continue repairing your system with homebrew next.

Answer (score 0):

I hope nobody goes through this but in case you are unlucky like me, this is how I managed to fix it:

Open an [arch x86_64 terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/428769) session and uninstall the `x86_64` Homebrew alongside all its installed libs (you really need to open the terminal in `x86_64` mode, otherwise the uninstall script will remove the `arm64` Homebrew stuff):

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

[Reinstall rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) now in a `ARM64` terminal:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

At this point the installation process should fail showing you exactly which exact dynamic library wasn't present. In my case it was `libgmp`

```bash
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/andyruizgarramones/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/andyruizgarramones/.mkshrc /Users/andyruizgarramones/.profile /Users/andyruizgarramones/.bashrc.
    RVM PATH line not found for Zsh, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/andyruizgarramones/.profile /Users/andyruizgarramones/.bash_profile /Users/andyruizgarramones/.zlogin.
    Installing rvm gem in 2 gemsets./scripts/functions/gemset: line 134: 68320 Abort trap: 6           "${rvm_ruby_binary}" -rrubygems -e "$gem_spec" 2> /dev/null
dyld[68326]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
```

You should be fine by now since you can now see what's wrong and search how to fix it. In my case, I had to reinstall `gmp` and also deal with `cmake` and `pkg-config`

```bash
brew reinstall gmp
brew link gmp
brew reinstall cmake
brew reinstall pkg-config && brew unlink pkg-config && brew link pkg-config
```