# Rails app crashing on any valid route, dyld[random number]: missing symbol called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arm64, apple-silicon, dyld, apple-m2

I have switched to the M2 chip. I was able to run a few Rails apps without any issues.

Now I'm trying to set up a new Rails app and I'm able to create and migrate the database, starting the Rails server. But getting the below error when trying to load the page (the server crashes with the below error):

`dyld[91237]: missing symbol called` (No backtrace nothing just this line.)

Versions and a few gems
Ruby 3.0.2
Rails 7.0.8
thin
sqlite3

Tried removing and reinstalling all gems.

Similar posts already tried with no success:

1. [Mac M1 dyld missing symbol called on Ruby ARM64 installation via RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203712/mac-m1-dyld-missing-symbol-called-on-ruby-arm64-installation-via-rvm)
2. [rails on M2: dyld[...]: missing symbol called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447424/rails-on-m2-dyld-missing-symbol-called)
3. [dyld[xxxxx]: missing symbol called after update to ruby 3.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618549/dyldxxxxx-missing-symbol-called-after-update-to-ruby-3-1-4)
4. [dyld[****]: missing symbol called on rails commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76414309/dyld-missing-symbol-called-on-rails-commands)

If anyone was able to resolve this please guide.

Comment: set `config.eager_load = true` in development.rb and see if you get a better stack trace when running rails s